# Cannot log in to phpmyadmin with root password wampserver even after reconfiguring

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I am not able to log in to phpmyadmin with root password using wampserver on windows 7. Re-configuring it from mysql console is successful. However, the same password does not work on phpmyadmin GUI with new password.

I tried the following options and none of them allow me to log in to phpmyadmin after the first time:

1. Added following code in config.inc file

   ```
   cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
   cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
   cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
   ```
2. Updated password for root username using mysql console as below:

   ```
   UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('test') WHERE User='root';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
3. Tried completely reinstalling wampserver. I can log in the first time,re-logging in to phpmyadmin gives the same error again.

   Looking forward to any suggestions.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using?

Comment: What version of MYSQL are you using?

Comment: I am using Wampserver 3.0.6 64 bit x64 – Apache 2.4.23 – PHP 5.6.25/7.0.10 – MySQL 5.7.14 – PhpMyAdmin 4.6.4 – Adminer 4.2.5 – PhpSysInfo 3.2.5

Comment: Then when you run phpMyAdmin you should see a login screen, so there is no need to fiddle with phpMyAdmins `config.inc.php` file. If you change the password just use the new password when you next login

Comment: Yes, I tried to log in to phpMyAdmin without changing anything in phpMyAdmins config.inc.php file, but it gives me following error: Error

SQL query: Edit Edit

SET lc_messages = 'en_US';

MySQL said: Documentation
#1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'

Comment: Are you sure you dont have an old version of MYSQL on your system that is actually running instead of the MYSQL that comes with WAMPServer? This usually happens when using a new version phpMyAdmin and an old version of MySQL

Comment: I removed all the MySQL versions from my computer and restarted phpMyAdmin. This solved my error and I am able to log in to phpMyAdmin and wordpress eventually! Thank you for your help! :)